# Hosting Wordpress website on IIS

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to host a wordpress website in IIS. However, when i am browsing that website locally on my laptop, then i am getting the pop up whether i want to open or save 'wp-login.php' from localhost
The port number on which my website hosted is 807.
I am attaching the screen shot of my browser and IIS.
While the same website works from xampp server. Can anyone please help?

[browserScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdhRi.png)

[IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xJpM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your IIS server doesn't know how to handle php files. At first I would configure IIS to manage PHP files. Here is a dedicated [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/50432/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/)